# sublimegdb not working on osx 10.8

Tags: gdb, sublimetext3

I am trying to use sublimegdb with sublime text 3, on OSX 10.8

I check I have gdb , but could not start the gdb with sublimegdb plugin.

I am testing with a simple C++ program test.cpp, I build a debug version with name test in same directory .

my project settings are:

```js
{
    "build-system":
    {
        "cmd":
        [
            "g++",
            "${file}",
            "-g",
            "-o",
            "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"
        ],
        "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
        "selector": "source.c, source.c++",
        "working_dir": "${file_path}"
    },
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "sublimegdb_commandline": "gdb -nx -readnow -fullname --interpreter=mi -args ./test",
        "sublimegdb_workingdir": "."
    }
}
```